# How is this small note played?

Tags: notation

I have seen a bit about acciaccaturas and appoggiaturas but this is different to what I have seen. The small note is not connected, comes after the normal sized note, and is a dotted quarter note. How would you play this?
[image: Quarter note followed by a small dotted quarted note of the same pitch, not connected with a tie]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either as a quarter and an eighth note or as a three-eighths note, depending on the syllable count of the underwritten lyric stanzas/languages which you left out even though they are what is making the difference here.

At least that very much is my guess.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for adding an answer. In the future, when questions need more detail added, it can be helpful to just give comments until it's clarified. You can see some more about answering [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AndyBonner but the answer is clearly correct.  It's not clear _why_ there are two alternative rhythms given, but it is certainly clear that that's what's going on here.

Comment: @phoog Well, Occam's razor says this is about lyrics and syllables, but it *could* be an ossia (unlikely, since there's nothing better or easier about the dotted note), or a second voice (that for some reason is printed smaller; unlikely). If we knew for sure this is a song with lyrics, or that it's instrumental, that would open some new possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing (without knowing the context, especially the target instrument), it's not clear.

I think that one plays the A's on different strings (or on a piano, use the pedal) and then plays the F against a held A; then another A at the end.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like maybe you're mistaking the dotted note for a dotted half? I think it's most likely that it's an "ossia" situation, like for different syllables in different verses as others have suggested, but even if it's multiple voices, they'll only be two A's during the space of one A.

Comment: You're right. Now it makes less sense to me. Of course, on some instruments, one would still be able to play an A of one length against two A's of shorter length (I don't know if a listener could tell.) I'm guessing the piece is in 6/8 but that doesn't help.